# Python regridding a 2D rotated mesh grid

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, grid, interpolation

I have a 2D rotated rectangular grid with longitude and latitude values with dimension [405, 555] and I can't understand how to regrid it, I want a rectangular grid with the axis "parallel" to Parallels and Meridians.

I tried to use scipy interpolation functions as: griddata or RegularGridInterpolator, but I always have problem with the old grid dimension because they are 2D and rotated, the values are not repeated and I don't know how to solve it.

Sorry I can't post my original code and data because they are proprietary and I don't know how to create a MWE.

I tried this:

```
import scipy.interpolate.ndgriddata as ndgriddata
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(35.0, 42.0, 405) # my new longitude
y = np.linspace(36.0, 48.0, 555) # my new latitude
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# grid_lon: old 2D array [405, 555] for the longitude
# grid_lat: old 2D array [405, 555] for the latitude
# data: old 2D array [405, 555] for the data
test = ndgriddata.griddata((grid_lon, grid_lat), data, (X, Y), method="linear")
```

but, of course I obtain the error:

> ValueError: invalid shape for input data points

I know like this is complicated to answer it but if someone have an idea, please let me know.

Thanks,

Ciccio

Comment: Hi @cicciodevoto - I am also interested in this problem. But can you please clarify or show in your ode more clearly which scipy functions you are using? It is not clear where ndgriddata.griddata comes from. Cheers

Comment: Hi @dreab sorry you are right, I updated including the imports. ndgriddata comes from scipy.interpolate, I hope this can help you, if you have any other question let me know :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just to flatten the old coordinates and the data.

```
ndgriddata.griddata((grid_lon.flatten(), grid_lat.flatten()), 
                    data.flatten(), (X, Y), method="linear")
```